# Youtube Embedded Iframe playlist reversedPosition

Tags: iframe, youtube, sql-order-by

I am using an embedded iframe youtube player to display youtube video lists.
I want to use the parameter: playlist reversedPosition.

It seems not to work and I can't find any details online about if it's deprecated or not etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

This is my code:

```
<div class="yt"><iframe name="video_player" id="video_player" type="text/html" width="940" height="528.75" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=playlist&list=PL1941062C95EECEA3&loop=1&modestbranding=1&autohide=0&vq=hd1080&origin=http://www.aquariusage.com&showinfo=1&orderby=reversedPosition" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an API issue, there seems to be others with the same problem.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3720